# Showing that $|z^{n+1}-z^n|=|z-1|$

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-numbers

I need to show that $|z^{n+1}-z^n|=|z-1|$ where $z$ is a complex number, and the series $\{ a_{n} \} ^\infty _{n=1}$ is defined as $a_n=z^n$. It is assumed that $|z|=1$.

I'm having trouble showing that :/

Comment: $$|ab|=|a||b|$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that
$$|z^{n+1} - z^n| = |z^n(z - 1)| = |z^n| \cdot |z - 1| = |z|^n \cdot |z - 1| = |z - 1|.$$

Comment: I can't believe I didn't see that. Thank you.